# iPhone takes media queries for min-width: 768px

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a landing page where the css is structured like this:

```
body {
    background: white;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

On both desktop Safari and iPhone (tested on a real, actual iPhone 6S device), **body background is red**. Whatever I try to apply (device-ratio x2, etc), I just can't manage to make the background `blue` on an iPhone.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out I had to add this in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Everything works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Original iphone screen width in pixels is 768px, even the iphone 6s is still scaled from that. So a device-ratio x2 means that a full width css element on the screen is screenwidth/2 in css pixels.

Why would we do that? Because it means that a X cm width screen is always Y pixels width in css.

I don't know what's gonna happen with increased density displays in the future. It wouldn't make sense to use 1080px css for a 8k screen. Maybe the naming will be changed from px into something more generic like dp on android apps.